# Webservice with Return

Tags: java, database, webmethod

My Apps: Netbeans (8.0.1), Apache Tomcat

I have here a Webservice and Webmethod.
User should insert a number (Sozialversicherungsnummer (SVN)). He should get as Return the corresponding name ("Nachname"). The table in the database is called "kunden". Fields: "Sozialversicherungsnummer" and "Nachname".

```
@WebMethod( operationName = "SVN-Abfrage" )
   public String svn(int SVN)
   {
      try
      {
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection( 
         DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD );
         statement = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery( "SELECT Nachname FROM kunden WHERE Sozialversicherungsnummer='" + SVN +"'" );

         // if requested seat is available, reserve it
         if ( resultSet.next() )
         {
            return resultSet.getString("Nachname");
         } // end if
            return "fehler";
      } // end try
      catch ( SQLException e )
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return ("1");
      } // end catch
      catch ( Exception e )
      {
         e.printStackTrace();  
      return ("2");
      } // end catch
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
         } // end try
         catch ( Exception e )
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ("3");
         } // end catch
      } // end finally
   } // end WebMethod
```

I test the Webservice with SOAP UI. Unfortunately, there is an error in my code.

I always get "3" as return. When I delete my "finally" section i get "1" as return. When I also delete this, i get "2" as return... It doesn't matter what I insert: Any number like "123" or a right "Sozialversicherungsnummer" from Database which SHOULD work.

I want to get a Integer from the User, and to return a corresponding Name ("Nachname"). Much more complicated as I thought :-/

Would be kind if somebody could help me.

Greetz

Comment: What do you get? is there an error or "no records found" ?

Comment: I updated the question. -> I always get "3" as return. When I delete my "finally" section i get "1" as return. When I also delete this, i get "2" as return... It doesn't matter what I insert: Any number like "123" or a right "Sozialversicherungsnummer" from Database which SHOULD work.

Comment: Try executing that SQL statement directly on the back-end database. If it succeeds on the database producing the desired result-set then, embed it into your Java code and finally if the Java code succeeds, implement webservices of your interest.

Comment: i tried it with MYSQL workbench: http://www.youscreen.de/wqjjwlew19.jpg here it works. in Java not...

Comment: Does it work without webservices? If not then, try executing the plain Java code removing webservices. You will be able to see the exact culprit.

Comment: Update: I have created a new Project without Webservice. Result: It works!

Here a Screen: http://www.youscreen.de/wutlkxgz18.jpg

Now I would like to do this in a Webservice without Problems........ Maybe somebody sees anything what I should change in the Webmethod above. I dont really see it :/

Thank you all very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
statement.executeQuery( "SELECT \"*\" FROM \"kunden\"" + "WHERE (\"Sozialversicherungsnummer\" = '" + SVN + "')" );
```

With

```
statement.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM kunden WHERE Sozialversicherungsnummer='" + SVN +"'" );
```

Also you can optimize your code in the exception blocks. Instead of

```
String i= "Kann nicht gefunden werden";
return i;
```

You can

```
return  "Kann nicht gefunden werden";
```

Comment: Ok i changed the statement, but I still have problems. I updated the question, maybe you can help. Thanks!

Comment: So, if you are getting 1 as the return value, there is clearly a SQLException. Can you also paste the Exception stack trace